# Twilio PCI Compliant <Gather> in Function Widget with Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I've been stalking around here and have gotten most of my answers as I make my way through this new tool, but I'm now stuck and need some direct advice.

The Gather function in Studio is not PCI compliant, so I have to shift my call to a Function and return the parsed data--I finally figured out how to do that one--however, I've found that I cannot call the web service housed within the single function and had to send the  with event.Digits to another function to make the web service call to my token provider. This works, however it has led to a strange result: my token is read back as TTS and then the call is hung up. I have no TTS action in play. Below are my sets of code:

Initial function called from Studio:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    twiml.gather({
        input: 'dtmf',
        finishOnKey: '#',
        timeout: 10,
        action: 'paymenttest',
        method: 'GET'
    }).say('Enter CC');

    console.log(twiml);
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

This successfully calls my function with the digits entered:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    const url ='my payment gateway' + event.Digits + '&EXPDATE=1220&CARDTYPE=VI';

    got.get(url, {
        headers: {
            'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // Check the response and ask your second question here
        event.callback(null, response.body);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Boo, there was an error.
        callback(error)
    });
};
```

This successfully returns the token....but as mentioned prior...it's read back out to me instead of getting included in the data returned back to Studio.

Comment: Have you checked out the <Pay> verb: https://www.twilio.com/pay  Its offers a PCI compliant way to accept credit card information via phone calls.

Comment: Hey Devin, unfortunately the pay verb locks you to only using Stripe, but Gather is also pci compliant and works just fine...just need Studio to properly read the body of the second function called.

Comment: @rasstwo I think you mibht want to do just `callback()` instead of `event.callback()` in your .then of the second function.

Comment: Thanks, tried the change but it still reads the token without being told to.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Right now Studio is not well setup for using TwiML from a Twilio Function and then continuing the flow. In your case when you return the token from your second Function Twilio is dealing with it as if you just returned text to a regular TwiML webhook. When this happens Twilio defaults to assuming you meant `<Say>` and reads out the text.

While the team work on redirecting calls back into Studio flows there is a workaround.

Instead of returning the token in the second Function, return some TwiML that includes a [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) to your Studio flow's webhook URL with `?FlowEvent=audioComplete` appended. You will also need to add a dummy Say/Play widget after your Function widget (it becomes the next part in the flow that can trigger an "audio complete" message, so exists to collect that and send on to the next widget).

The only thing that we haven't handled in thie workaround is sending the token to the flow. I don't believe we can do this via this redirect workaround, so instead I'd recommend storing the token in your own database or something like a [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync) object. This way you can use it outside of Studio however you like. If you need it within the Studio flow then you can create one more Function that returns the token as JSON, and that will be stored within the flow variables then.

If you would prefer to use [`<Pay>`](https://www.twilio.com/pay), as this would be a lot easier, I also recommend [requesting the pay connector you need](https://www.twilio.com/pay/request-connector).

Comment: Thanks Phil. The redirect back to the flow's webhook was something I noticed it was attempting when you leave out the action url, but hadn't messed with it yet. I'll give it a shot and see what I can get out of it. Otherwise, I was going to simply make the entire IVR out of chained functions versus Studio widgets.

Comment: Let me know if it does work for you! Otherwise you could certainly chain a bunch of Functions to achieve the same.

Comment: In regards to setting another function to return the token as JSON, are you saying to run another function immediately after to grab the returned token? The function will hold that data there to be called like a database?

Comment: Hmm. I guess you don't necessarily need the token to be part of the Studio flow itself, you just need to send it somewhere that you are going to use it to make the charge. Perhaps you can ignore what I'm saying about getting the token into the flow!

Comment: Preferably, I'd like to return it to the flow as I'd like to use the success/fail from there to offer different options/redirect to a call center.

Comment: So I’d store it somewhere and then retrieve it using a function that returns JSON.

Comment: Hey Phil, I'm ever so closer...however I've run into another issue that will need solving...the 5 second timeout of functions. I can make multiple calls in a row and all will be well, then suddenly I'll get a block of failures. I reduced some of these by removing unnecessary params passing from function to function, but my most important one--the one that actually sends out the token to apply payment--is now the only inconsistent function timewise. Any thoughts to get past the 5 second rule?

Comment: var got = require('got');
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    const url = 'mygateway/PayFees?Number=12345&Number2=3&paymentToken=ID:0002&paymentAmount=5.00'
 
    got.post(url, {
    headers: {        
    'content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +event.oAuth}    
})
  .then(function(response) {console.log(response.body);
   var IsSuccess = JSON.parse(response.body).IsSuccess;
   twiml.redirect('/paysuccess?paymentAmount=5.00&IsSuccess='+IsSuccess);
   callback(null, twiml);
  });};

Comment: Is the real issue that your payment provider's API request takes more than 5 seconds which is timing out the Twilio function? I'm checking to see if we can extend the timeout, but it may be that you need to take that part of the Twilio platform. Running your own AWS Lambda function (which has a longer timeout) might be a plan here. If I do find out that we can extend it, I'll let you know though.

Comment: It very well could be, we are looking into that as well. I've also come up with another solution to call the service, give it the token and get a simple response, send the call to a hold, a service on our side performs the processing and then calls a function webhook or studio flow with the data, I'll then have twiml to find call in queue, pass the params, and redirect to another function to work the results of the payment.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Making it more of a background process and updating once it’s done is a better experience for the caller too. I’ll let you know if I hear about longer execution times on Functions though.

Comment: Alright, it works well; however, if there is a latency issue in just me getting back a "confirmed handoff," I'll lose the call. I've been playing around with the callback() to try to get it to let me fire and forget on the web service call, but I can only have it wait to receive a response or skip the http request altogether. Any suggestions on getting the function to ignore waiting for a response and just send the call straight to hold music after shooting out the request?

Comment: I've come up with a workaround: Using the timeout option in the Got() module, I force it to error out of the request. Since I'm guaranteeing a error every time, I then removed .then(response) and replaced it with .catch(error) and placed the twiml.redirect there. This way, I know for certain what happens on every attempt: it will error out after I've sent the request and doesn't rely on a timely response to move on, knowing that a response comes later and will redirect based on the results anyway.

Comment: Glad you've got a workaround. The way that Twilio Functions are built, once you make the `callback` the function is shut down, so there's no fire and forget.

Answer (score 0):

I think philnash answer here got old, even when it still works.

Right now, you should have to call the first function using TwiML Redirect node.

In the second function, you should have to add a redirect to the webhook of the flow adding ?`FlowEvent=return&foo=bar` (where `foo=bar` should be changed by the info you really want to return).

Comment: and what are the benefits of this?

Comment: What philnash explained was a workaround, where you have to add a dummy widget. With this solution, you do not need the dummy widget, the return goes to the same redirect widget. Also, I am adding how to return info from the function.